# Bootnode issue of unknown peer

Tags: private-blockchain, synchronization, bootnodes

When I am running a bootnode on AWS for a private blockchain and creating it, multiple peers are pinging it. What issues can arise, and how can I prevent other peers that we haven't connected from pinging it?
[image]